# Angular2 routing fails on empty route

Tags: angular, typescript

I have set up my routing like this

I have the first level routing in the app module

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, },

 { path: 'dash', redirectTo:"dashboard" },
 { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
 })
```

And in the app component`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Then i have a dashboard module where i have set another routing config as

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',  //null path to use dashboardtemplate which contains sidebar links
   component: DashboardTemplateComponent,
   children: [
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,

  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent, //dashboard is another component

  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent,
  },


   ]
 }

 ];

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
 ],
 exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

I also have dashboard template component as

```
@Component({
  template: `
      <dash-side></dash-side> //sidebar links in the dashboard
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class DashboardTemplateComponent implements OnInit {

//here the logic is if a user is loggedin navigate to dashboard else to login

  }
```

The reason why i set it this way is so that the profile and users components can use the sidebar links set in the `DashboardTemplate component`

The problem is that when using profile in the dashboard route it always falls back to not found component, How do i resolve this issue

Comment: There is some issue with you router links , are you using absolute paths, or abstract ones eg- 'profile' or '/profile'. beacuse the link changes when you add slash to the router link, try and hover on the text and look at the link its redirecting to

Comment: Can you also share your app.module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues.

- Redirect route requires a slash prefix and `pathMatch`
- Import RouterModule as `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` in the main
  routes file.
- Import RouterModule as `RouterModule.forRoot()` to `imports` in the `AppModule`.

This should solve your problem.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'dash',
        redirectTo:"/dashboard",  // <=== prefix slash
        pathMatch: 'full'         // <=== Add 'pathMatch'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: NotFoundComponent
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],  // <=== change to forChild()
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
```